# RPC Error when running more than 21 tests via VSTest adapter in Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, testcomplete, vstest

Our Azure DevOps pipeline seems to fails after executing exactly 21 tests. It seems like there is some invisible hard limit that's stopping execution after 21 tests. It was working last week with no changes made between then and now. I can't seem to figure out the issue so I thought I would try my luck here.

Here's the output of the failure: (Can't seem to post the full output so here's the relevant portion)

```
Starting the ALIFEMGSelectionTest_17 test...
  Passed ALIFEMGSelectionTest_16 [48 s]
Starting the ALIFEMGSelectionTest_18 test...
  Passed ALIFEMGSelectionTest_17 [49 s]
Starting the ALIFEMGSelectionTest_19 test...
  Passed ALIFEMGSelectionTest_18 [54 s]
Starting the ALIFEMGSelectionTest_20 test...
  Passed ALIFEMGSelectionTest_19 [1 m]
Starting the ALIFEMGSelectionTest_21 test...
  Passed ALIFEMGSelectionTest_20 [59 s]
Starting the ALIFEMGSelectionTest_22 test...
  Passed ALIFEMGSelectionTest_21 [59 s]
##[error]ALIFEMGSelectionTest_22 test: The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)
##[error]ALIFEMGSelectionTest_23 test: Unable to activate the "ALIFEMGSelectionTest_23" test due to the following error: The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
  Skipped ALIFEMGSelectionTest_22 [46 s]
The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
  Skipped ALIFEMGSelectionTest_23
Results File: C:\_work\_temp\TestResults\admin_Desktop-09-30_15_13_56.trx
##[error]Test Run Failed.
Total tests: 21
     Passed: 21
 Total time: 18.7192 Minutes
Vstest.console.exe exited with code 1.
**************** Completed test execution *********************
Test results files: C:\_work\_temp\TestResults\DESKTOP.trx
Created test run: 3872
Publishing test results: 23
Publishing test results to test run '3872'.
TestResults To Publish 23, Test run id:3872
Test results publishing 23, remaining: 0. Test run id: 3872
Published test results: 23
Publishing Attachments: 1
Execution Result Code 1 is non zero, checking for failed results
Completed TestExecution Model...
##[warning]Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\_work\_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c9\2.170.1\Modules\DTAExecutionHost.exe' failed with exit code 1
##[error]Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.
Finishing: VSTest
```